# Can you animate a svg "background-image"?

Tags: html, css, svg, background-image, svg-animate

I want to center a svg-image horzontal and vertical responsive to my window. So I decided to integrate the image in a div background. Now when i want to add stroke-dasharray's and animations with stroke-dashoffset to my svg it doesn't work.

Is this posibble to animate a svg background image?

The svg-image consists only out of many lines.
**Here my svg file (there are much more lines with only different x and y values):**

```css
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 1920 1200"  xml:space="preserve">
<g id="Layer_1">

<line class="path" stroke-linecap="round" fill="none" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="3" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="960" y1="600" x2="2346.139" y2="-42.064"/>

</g>
</svg>
```

**And here my Html and Css files:**

```css
html, body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
}

.Container {
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url(Space.svg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}


.path {
  stroke-dasharray: 20;
}
```

```html
  <body>
    <div class="Container">
    </div>
  </body>
```

Comment: This is worth a look https://github.com/jrummyapps/AnimatedSvgView

Comment: /search?q=svg+animate+transform or /search?p=svg+animate+transform did you search ? :)

Comment: You must put the CSS in the SVG image file itself and not in the container HTML file or a separate CSS file.

Comment: I don't see any attempt to animate anything in the question so I can't really create an answer showing you what to do as I don't really know what it is you're trying to do.

Comment: Its very much possible to animate SVG background. This website http://myapic.com does an awesome job with the animation

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can animate ... but only in browsers that support it - out you go IE and some other browsers (Edit, as of 2018 Edge now supports this).

This example uses CSS for the animation ... I have successfully used `<animate>` tags but have not tested extensively.

```css
.svg {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml;charset=UTF-8,%3Csvg width='300' height='70' viewBox='0 0 300 70' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cstyle type='text/css'%3E %23a%7Banimation:x .5s ease alternate 14%7D%40keyframes x%7Bfrom%7Bfill:%23c2c2c2%7Dto%7Bfill:%23fff%7D%7D%3C/style%3E%3Crect id='a' x='14' y='23' width='28' height='28' fill='%23c2c2c2' /%3E%3Crect x='52' y='33' width='100' height='11' fill='%23c2c2c2' /%3E%3C/svg%3E");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  min-height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="svg">Look at my background</div>
```

Note the actual encoded SVG used above (that I have used in production for an inline UX improvement for a slow-loading google recaptcha iframe) is:

```
<svg width="300" height="70" viewBox="0 0 300 70" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <style type="text/css">
        #a { animation: x .5s ease alternate 14; }

        @keyframes x {
           from { fill: #000; }
             to { fill: #fff; }
        }
    </style>
    <rect id="a" x="14" y="23" width="28" height="28" fill="#000" />
    <rect x="52" y="33" width="100" height="11" fill="#000" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Ok cool. It works now, thanks. So my fault was that i tried to animate it in the css file, but you wrote the "style" into the image code. I actually didn't know that you could do that. But is there a way to control the animation from outside, so for example when you click a button the animation should start/stop?

Comment: Not with a background image ... an alternative would be to swap a class that has a bg with a non-animated version of the image ... the css will gzip very well.

Comment: you could try SVG-SMIL animation ... but that does not work in IE or Edge either.

Comment: Anyone interested, I used my tool at https://codepen.io/elliz/pen/ygvgay to encode the SVG into CSS.

Comment: Works great, thank you for the answer and for the encoding tool, really pro tool.

Comment: This is another [tool for encoding SVG to CSS (with live preview)](https://yoksel.github.io/url-encoder/)